# Where are these choices of $A',B',C'$ for this quadratic form?

Tags: analytic-geometry

I'm studying quadratic forms: In the book I'm reading, he starts by looking at quadratic forms such as:

$$\varphi (x,y)=Ax^2+2Bxy+Cy^2$$

And that given this quadratic form, one can introduce via axis rotation the new coordinates $(s,t)$ with:

$$x= as-bt \quad \quad \quad y= bs-at$$

And

$$a=\cos \theta \quad \quad \quad \quad b=\sin \theta$$

And then this reduces to:

$$\varphi(x,y)=\varphi(as-bt,\; bs-at)=A's^2+2B'st+C't$$

Where:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
  {A'}&=&{Aa^2+2Bab+Cb^2} \\ 
  {B'}&=&{-Aab+B(a^2-b^2)+Cab} \\ 
  {C'}&=&{Ab^2-2Bab-Ca^2} 
\end{eqnarray*}$$

I don't understand why $A',B',C'$ becomes that. Shouldn't:

$$\varphi(as-bt,\; bs-at)\stackrel{?}{=}A (a s-b t)^2+2 B (a s-b t) (b s-a t)+C (b s-a t)^2$$

In a trial to do something similar to what he did, I took one term and expanded:

$$C (b s - a t)^2=b^2 C s^2 - 2 a b C s t + a^2 C t^2=s^2(b^2 C-2abCs^{-1}+a^2Cts^{-2})$$

And I guess that $(b^2 C-2abCs^{-1}+a^2Cts^{-2})$ would be my $C'$, but it's very different from the $C'$ given by the book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you expand all terms, you should combine similar terms.

$$A(as-bt)^2+2B(as-bt)(bs-at)+C(bs-at)^2\\
=Aa^2s^2-2Aabst+Ab^2t^2+2Babs^2-2Ba^2st-2Bb^2st+2Babt^2+Cb^2s^2-2Cabst+Ca^2t^2\\
=(Aa^2+2Bab+Cb^2)s^2+2(-Aab+B(a^2-b^2)+Cab)st+(Ab^2-2Bab-Ca^2)t^2$$

With this you can define the $A',B',C'$ as desired.